# make primary key with 2 fields in Django?

Tags: database, django

I want to make a primary key from 2 fields in Django.

**Fields are below**

```
- current Time 
- userId
```

How Can I do this??

```
Time + userid {PK }  [ Current Time + userid]
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most of the time, you don't actually need your multi-column key to be the primary key.

Django operates best with surrogate keys - that is, it automatically defines an autoincrement field called `id` and sets that to be the primary key. That suits for almost all uses.

If you then need to enforce a unique constraint on your model across two or more fields, you can use the `unique_together` setting in the inner `Meta` class.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800375/how-can-set-two-field-primary-key-for-my-models-in-django) to understand the working of surrogate keys..

Answer (score 7):

It's not built into Django (see [#373](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373)), but see the bottom of http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys for the discussion.  I've copied over the "alternative methods" section here for posterity.

**Alternative methods**

> notnotpeter: Currently, you can "fake"
>   it by declaring one of the keys to be
>   primary in Django and adding a unique
>   constraint to the model. (needs more
>   info...examples?)
>
> mjm: This only works when there is a
>   non-compound unique key to use, if I
>   understand what's being proposed here.
>   As such, it may be workable as a way
>   to squeeze a design that naturally has
>   CKs into Django, but it's of no use
>   for working with an existing schema
>   that has only the CK.
>
> djansoft: It can be done using
>   unique-together.
>
> Tobu: You can't use just one key. A
>   use case for illustration: a
>   NamespacedTag? model with a CK made of
>   a namespace and a name. The primary
>   key can't be just the namespace or
>   just the name since that would be
>   ambiguous. The only solution (and I
>   dislike it since it is bad modelling
>   and forces database accesses to be
>   serialized on a counter) is to use an
>   AutoField?.
>
> toszter: Call me nutty, but why not
>   declare any number of columns as
>   primary key in your model, which
>   django then uses to create a "hidden"
>   pk_composite column that's just a hash
>   of the three pk values in the row?
>   When you do a lookup on a pk, you
>   assume the ENTIRE combination of
>   values is the primary key, nothing
>   more or less. So when you look up
>   according to the values needed to
>   create the full pk_composite, the hash
>   always computes and if the hash
>   algorithm is public, can be used off
>   the URL, the querystring in db
>   lookups, and just about anywhere.
>   Seems pretty simple in my mind but
>   then again I am not going into great
>   detail here.

That being said, I would create an ID on the table and make that the primary key.  Then add a unique contraint on the user_id + timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

If the key has to be single-column:

id is added "out-of-the-box" (variable.id) and for current time just add

```
from django.db import models

date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
```

in yourapp/models.py

so you have your 2 values, out of witch you can make your key in any shape you want.

if you want multi-column-key then read the other answer. Hope to help you.

Comment: actually userid field is foreign key ,which is a primary key of user table thats why I am confused how to do this?