# Django IntegrityError while updating a record

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model with double columns as primary key. I do a filter on it and get the records I want, change a field and save it. As I know save will update the record and does not create a new instance of the model in db. so It should be all okay but I'm stuck with an integrityError `Duplicate entry '10-2' for key 'PRIMARY'` when I try to save the record

Here is the code snippet:

```
analysis = AnalysisResult.objects.filter(request=req.request_id)
for anal in analysis:
    anal.analysisresult_path = some_string
    anal.save() #this line is where the error occurs
```

And here is my model:

```
class AnalysisResult(models.Model):

    analysisresult_path = models.CharField(db_column='analysisResult_path', max_length=255, blank=True,
                                       null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    detectionresult_path = models.CharField(db_column='detectionResult_path', max_length=255, blank=True,
                                        null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    targetcode = models.ForeignKey('TagetCode', models.DO_NOTHING,
                               db_column='targetCode_id')  # Field name made lowercase.
    request = models.ForeignKey('Request', models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'analysis_result'
        unique_together = (('request', 'targetcode'),)
```

Comment: `AnalysisResult.objects.filter(request=req.request_id)`  filter by primary key is equal some value you should to get only one record is it? why you do loop?

Comment: @BearBrown `unique_together = (('request', 'targetcode'),)` request_id + targetcode_id makes a record unique together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, yes, welcome to one of [django's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131616/6043170) [strongest opinions](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys):  all tables/models should have a single primary key field that can be used for updates.  If you don't have this, you must write raw SQL for the update since `save` will assume that there is an implicit primary key field called id to use in the `where` clause.