# how to join a query on non primary key and foreign key column in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have two model,  making unique key column as foreign key to other table.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    EmployeeId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Employee_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Release(models.Model):
    EmployeeId = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="EmployeeId")
```

when i am trying join query it is doing join on primary key column on Employee table.

below is the join query  I am expecting join on `Employee.EmployeeId =Release.EmployeeId`

```
r=Release.objects.all().select_related('EmployeeId')
```

but above query gives

```
print(str(r.query))
```

Output:

```
'SELECT "app_release"."id", "app_release"."EmployeeId_id", "app_employee"."id", "app_employee"."EmployeeId", "app_employee"."Employee_Name" 
FROM "app_release" INNER JOIN "app_employee" 
ON ("app_re
lease"."EmployeeId_id" = "app_employee"."id")'
```

which i don't want i.e, instead of

```
ON ("app_release"."EmployeeId_id" = "app_employee"."id")'
```

i want

```
ON ("app_release"."EmployeeId_id" = "app_employee"."EmployeeId")'
```

Comment: Did you run `makemirations` and `migrate`?

Comment: yeah , i have done.

Comment: form.save is working with foreign key empoyee.EmpoyeeId..

i have one data in Employee table : id=1, employeeid=123, Name='xyz'.

in Release form.
i am giving employeeid=123, and saving the form. its working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131616/5921826

Answer (score 3):

So you need to declare Employee.EmployeeId as primary key and remove unique key because Primary key is unique itself.
try this code..in Employee Model

`EmployeeId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)`

if you do not want to modify the table,then you can use raw query,please refer the link below

[raw query in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/)

please let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: Any other option without modification of table.