# How to set 2 attributes to primary key together in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in Django:

```
 class Subject(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_seats = models.IntegerField()
    subject_details = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

For the `Subject` table I want the `level` and the `subject_name` together to be primary keys. In fact, I dont want any other objects to have the same name and level. I know I can use `unique_together` but where do I mention the `primary_key = True`?

Comment: You don't. In Django one can *not* use multiple attributes together as primary key. It has been requested multiple times, but somehow is apparently not easy to do.

Comment: Do you know anything I can do as an alternative?

Comment: why make it a primary key? You can just use the `id = AutoField()`. There are some libraries, but these are all quite old (https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey not updated since 2015). The main problem is not the primary key at the database level, but the fact that a lot of Django's framework, and packages built on top of Django assume that `some_subject.pk` will be a singular value.

Comment: See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800375/how-can-i-set-two-primary-key-fields-for-my-models-in-django), I think this answer is what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **don't**. Django does not work with *composite primary keys*. This is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> Each model requires **exactly one** field to have `primary_key=True` (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

In the [*FAQ section*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/models/#do-django-models-support-multiple-column-primary-keys) it also continues with:

> Do Django models support multiple-column primary keys?
>
> **No**. Only single-column primary keys are supported.
>
> But this isn’t an issue in practice, because there’s nothing stopping
>   you from adding other constraints (using the `unique_together` model
>   option or creating the constraint directly in your database), and
>   enforcing the uniqueness at that level. Single-column primary keys are
>   needed for things such as the admin interface to work; e.g., you need
>   a single value to specify an object to edit or delete.

It is a feature that is often requested (see for example this [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373)), but it was not implemented. It will probably be quite cumbersome, first of all a lot of existing Django tooling will need to be updated (for example `JOIN`s should be done with the two keys, `FOREIGN KEY`s should then result in two or more fields constructed, etc.). But another, and probably even more severe problem might be the large number of packages built on top of Django that make the assumption that the primary key is not a composite. It would thus break a lot of packages in the Django "ecosystem".

There are some packages like [**`django-compositekey`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey) that aim to implement this. But the last update is made in october 2014.

It is not per se a problem not to make it a primary key. In fact Django's [**`GenericForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) only works if the primary keys are all of the same type. So using `unique_together` should be sufficient. Normally this will also make a `UNIQUE INDEX` at the databaes side.

Comment: So should I just add a meta class with unique_together and not mess with the primary key?

Comment: @iscream: I think that is indeed the best, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this 2 fields indexed by database because the main cause of primary key is to make field unique and indexed by the DBMS, so you can make your fields `unique_together` in Meta class and set `db_index=True` in field args.

Comment: What does db_index=True do? Do I need to put it on both the attributes?

Comment: that index your field on the database table, yes you can use it on both of your fields.