# How are many-to-many relationship handled in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-design, relational-database

I have a shirt which can contain multiple colors, and multiple colors which can have multiple shirts. Normally I would express it the following way:
[image]

In django I have the many-to-many (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)
Example:

```
publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

--
Can I create the table "Item_colors" consisting of 2 columns (no "ID" primary key) and design the models according to my diagram using the composite key:

```
class Item_colors(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('cloth_item_id', 'color_id'),)

    cloth_item_id = models.ForeignKey(Cloth_item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color_id = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How is the many-to-many relation handled in a DB context, and does it yield better performance?

EDIT: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys no avoiding primary keys in favor of composite keys saving columns :( at least for now..

Comment: A `ManyToManyField` creates an intermediate table, but with a primary key. In Django every model has a primary key.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I assume the intermediate table is similar to my "Item_colors" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the many-to-many relation handled in a DB context, and does it yield better performance?

With a junction table in the middle, so with an `item_colors` table. But the table contains a primary key, as does every model in Django.

If you do not specify a [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to define the model for the junction table yourself, Django will automatically create such model. This model then has two `ForeignKey`s to the two models it connects as discussed in the [*database representation* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#id1):

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an **intermediary join table** to represent the many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the name of the table for the model that contains it. Since some databases don’t support table names above a certain length, these table names will be automatically truncated and a uniqueness hash will be used, e.g. `author_books_9cdf`. You can manually provide the name of the join table using the `db_table` option.

But the table thus has a primary key. This might be useful if the same object occurs a second time in the relation.

You can access the through model in the `Article`-`Publication` example for example with:

```
Article.publications.through
```

You thus can define a through model yourself, for example with:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ClothItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Color,
        related_name='cloth_items'
        through='ClothItemColors'
    )

class ClothItemColors(models.Model):
    cloth_item = models.ForeignKey(ClothItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'item_colors'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('cloth_item', 'color'),
                name='unique_cloth_color'
            )
        ]
```

often an explicit through model is used to store extra information, for example the `quantity`:

```
class ClothItemColors(models.Model):
    cloth_item = models.ForeignKey(ClothItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # …
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, great help again -- and nice example usage of through. I dug into your use of the "UniqueConstraint" rather than my "unique_together" - the documentation agrees: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together..

I just miss whatever or not the I can avoid the primary key of the table saving a column, I have many similar tables :) or if it is as you say that all tables have a primary key (no exceptions)

Comment: I updated the original question as I found your other answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320317/how-to-set-2-attributes-to-primary-key-together-in-django and this on wiki:  https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys no avoiding primary keys in favor of composite keys saving columns :( at least for now..

Comment: @LeOverflow: well the sad thing is that Django's primary keys are quite "hardwired" in the rest of the code. For example a `DetailView` uses the `<int:pk>` URL path parameter to automatically filter. Likely it is possible to implement the changes in Django itself quite effectively, but then there is still the "ecosystem" of Django packages that depend on one primary key. So I think the refrain from fixing it, since it would likely introduce a lot of work to other package maintainers. Especially for packages that are not maintained for some time.