# Django - Created a web app which is linked to my PSQL, but when inserting data to one of my tables gives error for no ID

Tags: python, django, database, psql

I have a table where it has only two columns being exercise_id and muscle_id

```
create table if not exists exercise_muscle(
    exercise_id INT not null,
    muscle_id INT not null,
    primary key (exercise_id, muscle_id),
    foreign key (exercise_id) references exercise(exercise_id),
    foreign key (muscle_id) references muscle(muscle_id)
);
```

But when I try and insert data into this with the model seen below

```
class ExerciseMuscle(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey('Exercise', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    muscle = models.ForeignKey('Muscle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'exercise_muscle'
        unique_together = ('exercise', 'muscle')
```

I get this error where it tries to return exercise_muscle.id, which doesn't exist

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column exercise_muscle.id does not exist
LINE 1: ...xercise_id", "muscle_id") VALUES (1, 1) RETURNING "exercise_...
```

I have also checked my django dbshell and it looks all fine

```
\d exercise_muscle
             Table "public.exercise_muscle"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 exercise_id | integer |           | not null | 
 muscle_id   | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "exercise_muscle_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (exercise_id, muscle_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "exercise_muscle_muscle_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (muscle_id) REFERENCES muscle(muscle_id)
```

And checked my psql table and it doesn't have an id column

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple column primary keys are [not supported by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/faq/models/#do-django-models-support-multiple-column-primary-keys).

> **Do Django models support multiple-column primary keys?**
>
> No. Only single-column primary keys are supported.
>
> But this isn’t an issue in practice, because there’s nothing stopping
> you from adding other constraints (using the unique_together model
> option or creating the constraint directly in your database), and
> enforcing the uniqueness at that level. Single-column primary keys are
> needed for things such as the admin interface to work; e.g., you need
> a single value to specify an object to edit or delete.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61320607/9313033

Django expects a single primary key field. If you don't declare a PK field in the model declaration, Django will add a default AutoField called `id` when creating the migration for the model. You didn't declare a PK field, so Django expects the default. But the default field doesn't exist since you created the table by hand instead of by running the migrations.

Either add the primary key `id` field yourself by hand, or drop the table entirely and let Django create it by running `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`.