# How to make more than one fields primary key and remove auto generated id in django models

Tags: python, django

Suppose in a relational database schema we have a `student`, a `subject` and a `teacher` which connect to each other with a relation `teaches`. Also, the relation has an attribute `time` that stores the time of the lesson. This is the most complete yet simplified example I can think to describe my case. Now, the most pythonic and django-wise way I can think of trying to reach a correct solution is, after creating a model class for `student`, `subject` and `teacher`, to create a new class `Teaches`, which has the foreign keys for the three other classes; also it has the property date field for time. This class would look something like this:

```py
class Teaches(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete_models.CASCADE)
    subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete_models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete_models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateField

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            fields=['teachers', 'subjects', 'students']
            name='teacher_subject_student_triplet'
        ]
```

I added the `Meta` class because this is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800375/how-can-i-set-two-primary-key-fields-for-my-models-in-django) recommends as the correct approach.

The problem is that that in the migrations file I can still see the `id` field. The only way I've seen there is to remove it is to set another field as Primary Key, but in my case I cannot do that, having more than one keys. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=========== model.py =============

```
from django.db import models

class TeacherModel(models.Model):
    teacher_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_code

class SubjectModel(models.Model):
    subject_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_code
    
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_code
    

class Teaches(models.Model):
    custom_primary_key = models.SlugField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(SubjectModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateField

    
    @property
    def make_key(self):
        new_key = str(self.teacher.teacher_code + self.subject.subject_code + self.student.student_code)
        return new_key

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_primary_key = self.make_key
        super(Teaches, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

========= Output ==============

[image]

Comment: That's a nice trick! Thank you, I will accept as answer if no one else provides a better solution.

Comment: I have one more question: If you would like to filter all Teaches objects that have a teacher with id `te_101`, how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove autogenerated id by adding **primary_key=True**, see below code:

```
 class Person(models.Model):
      username = CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
      first_name = CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
```

setting a field to **primary_key=True** automatically makes it unique and not null.

Comment: This is precisely what I've said in the last paragraph. I cannot use primary key set to True because I have multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Controls the automatic generation of primary keys of each model if defined in settings.

Read this article:
[Set AutoField or BigAutoField on a per model basis](https://dev.to/weplayinternet/upgrading-to-django-3-2-and-fixing-defaultautofield-warnings-518n)