# Item in list but index is always 0

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset like this:

```
asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno = list(Asignaturas_Equivalencia.objects.filter(matricula=inscripcion.usuario.adicional.matricula, origen_de_equivalencia = "SEP").distinct())
```

then I loop over them and I print the index, if this is in the list and a property of the model:

```
for _as in asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno:
    print _as in asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno, asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno.index(_as), _as.clave_materia
```

and the result is different but the index, the index always returns 0, the output:

```
True 0 L1C115
True 0 L1PS101
True 0 L1C116
True 0 L1C118
True 0 L1PS105
True 0 L1PS107
True 0 L1PS109
True 0 L1PS111
True 0 L1C113
True 0 L1C114
True 0 L1C117
True 0 L1PS102
```

Thank you :)

**EDIT**

The model:

```
class Asignaturas_Equivalencia(models.Model):
    matricula = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    clave_materia = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    calificacion = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    origen_de_equivalencia = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'diccionario_equivalencias_materias'
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

The only solve for this question is to use enumerate.

Comment: why are you doing this? you know its in the list since you are looping through it ... it is strange that its index is always 0 ... what happens if you try printing the whole list?

Comment: You're going to want to change "as" to something else, so that your code doesn't blow up on newer versions of Python.

Comment: Sorry i have no as in my code as is only for demostration I'll change it

Comment: Show the code for the AE model.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2513473/98057

Comment: First there were two `primary_key=True`, now there's only one. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871966/make-primary-key-with-2-fields-in-django) is relevant?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo Yeah I had one more, But I think it does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and double-check your primary keys. It seems to me that they are the only things that could mess up your equality checks like this.

The `__eq__` method of Django's ORM returns `True` when two objects are of the same class *and* have the same pk. I'm guessing it gets confused when you have two fields with `primary_key = True`. It should throw some error afaik, but maybe it just leads to undefined behavior.

From [the Django Models documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> "Each model requires **exactly** one field to have primary_key=True
>   (either explicitly declared or automatically added)."

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: I already removed one primari_key and the index is always 0 :C

Comment: Well, then I'm out of guesses. Unless, somehow, all `_as.matricula` (whatever it is) are equal. Can you add it to your printout as well, since it is the pk?

Comment: Well I think is my problem because, any field in that model is repeated so no one can not be primari_key, and as the table was already done, I did not I only did the model to use it with django I had to put at least a primari_key

Comment: If you don't set a primary key explicitly (using `primary_key = True`), Django will create one for you (and it will be unique). Cheers.

Comment: Rail's Active Records take care of schema migrations quite nicely. Django seems to be going in the same direction. Maybe you're interested in [Simple Migrations](https://github.com/ricardochimal/simplemigrations/tree/master) and [Migratory](https://bitbucket.org/DeadWisdom/migratory/wiki/Home). If you're already running >=1.7 you should definitely check out [Django's schema migration commands `migrate` and `makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

Comment: I'm working with Django 1.3 and I use South, believe me if it was for me I had added an id field to the table, but i can not modified it, because I'm not the only one who uses it at my work

Answer (score 1):

You have different items, as is shown by `_as.clave_materia`. I wonder what this class definition looks like.

Maybe you wrote your own `__eq__` method, or similar. If you did, it might be buggy and always return `True` for the first element of your list of objects. Does it sound like an explanation?

Something like this (IPython session):

```
In [44]: class Foo:   
    def __eq__(self, s): return True
   ....:     

In [45]: a = Foo()

In [46]: b = Foo()

In [47]: a == b
Out[47]: True

In [48]: l = [a,b, Foo()]

In [49]: l
Out[49]: 
[<__main__.Foo at 0xb5c68b2c>,
 <__main__.Foo at 0xb670ad0c>,
 <__main__.Foo at 0xb5e0352c>]

In [50]: for item in l:
    print(l.index(item))
   ....:     
0
0
0
```

Comment: afaik its a django model class

Comment: I haven't written my own **__eq__** method, this is a django model

Answer (score 1):

As others have rightfully mentioned the equality test is probably fragile for the ordered iterable members.  But if you want to loop over contents and have indices then it is easier and more efficient to simply use enumerate.

```
for index,_as in enumerate(asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno):
     print _as in asignaturas_equivalencia_alumno, index, _as.clave_materia
```